# Visual Studio: Migrate Solution including Git from 2015 to 2017

Tags: git, migration, visual-studio-2017

I tried to migrate my VS 2015 Solution *FlatFileStore* to VS 2017, which uses a local Git repo and a remote repo on VisualStudio.com (VSTS). Opening the solution from VS 2017 was without any problem or conversion, I could also change code and commit the changes to the local git repo. But I could not sync the changes to the remote git repo. Git Synch used to work on VS 2015, but now it no longer works:

[image]

It seems, when I opened the solution in VS 2017 and committed a change, Git forgot about the remote repo and also VS 2015 does no longer remember it.

**2 Questions:**

1) What do I need to do that the same solution can be worked on using VS 2015 and 2017 without spoiling git ?

2) How can I tell VS2015 that the remote for *FlatFileStore* is on VSTS ? VS only allows me to publish, which would create a new repo on VSTS or to clone, which would create a new repo on my PC. I don't want to create a new repo, but connect 2 existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, for whatever reason, git has lost the remote.  You can check this easily by running `git remote` to see all of the existing remote repos.

If that is the case, you should be able to just add your remote back again.

```
git remote add origin https://yourAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/YourProject
```

VS should use the remotes configured in your git repo.  I don't know how or why your remote would have gotten removed, but it should be easy enough to get back to a working configuration.

Comment: Neither do I know what happened. I added the remote as you suggested,  noticed that the repo existed on VSTS, but that it was empty. I executed a publish from VS and it seems to work now. No idea, why the repo was empty, although I created it from VS only on the day I run into troubles.